# Can Visual Studio Code and VS 2012 be installed on same computer?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I would like to install Visual Studio Code on the same computer where I already have Visual Studio 2012 installed. Is this supported?

Comment: They're totally different programs.  It works fine.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Both are independent and yes you can install them. I have Visual Studio 2015 and Code on my Windows machine.

Comment: Thank you ShellZero. I will try it out.

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Comment: @Gouda Can you please confirm if the answer was helpful and could you mark it as an answer :)